# Swift UI MenuBarExtra: Bring second window to front

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm working on a MenuBar app and want to add a second window as a settings window to it. The second window should appear after clicking on a button in the MenuBar app. I got the window working, but it is behind other windows and I also get this warning on the console:

> [Window] Warning: Window SwiftUI.AppKitWindow 0x7fb562f0dcb0 ordered front from a non-active application and may order beneath the active application's windows.

My app file:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct pp: App {
        
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra(content: {
            ContentView()
        }, label: {
            Text("something")
        })
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
        
        Window("Settings", id: "settings-window") {
            VStack {
                Text("Some Text ...")
            }
            .frame(width: 350, height: 250)
        }.windowResizability(.contentSize)
        
    }
}
```

And the relevant section from `ContentView.swift`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow

    var body: some View {
        // ...

        Button(action: {
            openWindow(id: "settings-window")
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "gear")
        })

        // ...
    }
}
```

So how can I programmatically bring the settings window to the front?

Comment: I ran into the same problem but I was opening the window a little differently.  I found that if I had access to the NSWindow instance I could call `window?.orderFrontRegardless()` and then the new window would appear on top where I wanted it.

Answer (score 2):

What helped me is inserting
`NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` before the openWindow() command. So try it the following way:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow

    var body: some View {
        // ...

        Button(action: {
            NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
            openWindow(id: "settings-window")
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "gear")
        })

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works on my macbook.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow

    var body: some View {
        // ...
        Button(action: {
            openWindow(id: "settings-window")
            NSApplication.shared.windows.forEach { window in
                if window.identifier?.rawValue.starts(with: "settings-window") ?? false {
                    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
                    window.orderFrontRegardless()
                    return
                }
            }
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "gear")
        })
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very similar to the existing answer from July. What did you change, and why? Is this a new answer, or a "thank you"?